# How to tell Entity Framework to ignore properties in a complex property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Suppose I have these three classes:

```
public class ClassA {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ClassC ClassC { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ClassC ClassC { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC {
    public int Data1 { get; set; }
    public int Data2 { get; set; }
}
```

And in my database I have:

```
Table A
+------+--------+---------+
| A_ID | A_Name | A_Data1 |
+------+--------+---------+
|      |        |         |
+------+--------+---------+

Table B
+------+--------+---------+
| B_ID | B_Name | B_Data2 |
+------+--------+---------+
|      |        |         |
+------+--------+---------+
```

How can I tell Entity Framework (6.1.3) to ignore Data1 when mapping up ClassB, and ignore Data2 when mapping up classA?

Comment: I just verified that the following will not work: `modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>().Ignore(a => a.ClassC.Data2);` because Ignore expects a property, not a child property.

Comment: Could you not have ClassC_1 with Data1 and ClassC_2 with Data2 and they derived from ClassC?

Comment: @GaryF yes, I mean that is a good workaround but I'm reluctant to change the class structures too much because this is an API and I don't want to make any breaking changes. I'm sure you appreciate this is a simplified version of a much more complicated program. Ideally, I want a solution like Georg Patscheider alluded to above, but something that works. Perhaps there is no way to do it currently